# fsck each week, why?

Tags: hard-drive

i have installed operating system Ubuntu, but 
this message appears every day

```
  (Initramfs): /dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
  Inodes that were a part of a corrupted orphan linked lost found.
  /dev/sda1 : UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck manually.(I.e .,
  without -a or -p options). fsck exited with status code 4. The root
  filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
```

the i have to make this:

```
fsck /dev/sda6
```

my hd is ruined?  how can i solved this problem?

[image]

[image]

the result is:
[image]

[image]

now the result of SMART is:[image]

Comment: Let's find out: Look up how to run a SMART test on your hard drive.

Comment: @user535733 how can i solved this problem?

Comment: Your output indicates that it's not a problem to be *solved*. It's hardware that is *failing*. Follow @heynnema's advice on replacing your faulty hardware.

Comment: If you purchased the hard drive and it is still under warranty then contact the manufacturer for a replacement. If the hard drive came with the computer or it is out of warranty, buy a new one. The number of bad sectors should not go from 440 to 568. This is not good.

Comment: @user68186 my disk is 3.5 years old, can i use as external disk? i do the step of Hennema

Comment: Replace the hard disk as @heynnema says I'm the answer. This disk is bad.

Comment: @user68186 How many errors are you allowed to have a good disk, I want to buy a new one and first I want to verify the mistakes, should have 0 errors?

Comment: Within warranty the manufacturer will replace a drive with 1 bad sector. You decide how many you want to have.

Comment: 400-600 like you had, is too many. Many disks have 0-20 bad blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command should be `fsck -f /dev/sda6`

note: OP edited the question so the above answer isn't complete any more

---

**Update #1:**

From what little Spanish I know, it looks like your hard disk may be failing. We can try to bad block the disk and see if we can get it to work more reliably without all of the fsck's.

```
Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours
```

Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB/DVD.

In `terminal`...

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.

   -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
          used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
          same time as the -n or -p options.
```

**Update #2:**

After bad blocking the disk, we can see that the disk has failed.

Backup whatever data you can.

Replace the disk.

Reinstall Ubuntu and restore your data.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97345/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-fsck-each-week-why).